# Prove that $\lceil 2x\rceil =\lceil x\rceil +\lceil x+1/2\rceil$ -1 for all $x$ in $\mathbb R$

Tags: combinatorics, ceiling-and-floor-functions

I don't know how to approach the problem. I have searched for different ceiling and floor properties but none of them seemed to help. Or simply I just don't know how to tackle the question.

Comment: By inspection, this equation does not hold for $x\in(0,0.5]$.

Comment: Are you sure the question is not about the bracket function $[x]$ (= the largest integer $\le x$)? Then it has the virtue of being true! And was the key to one old IMO problem :-)

Comment: The two common identities are $$1 + \lceil{2x}\rceil = \lceil{x}\rceil + \lceil{x+1/2}\rceil \\ \lfloor{2x}\rfloor = \lfloor{x}\rfloor + \lfloor{x+1/2}\rfloor$$ Were you intending one of these instead?

Comment: That's not true is it?  $\lceil \frac 64\rceil = 2$ but $\lceil \frac 34\rceil =1$ and $\lceil \frac 54\rceil = 2$ but $2 \ne 3$.  Did you mean the floor function?

Comment: I am sorry I forgot to add (-1) at the end.

Answer (score 1):

This is false when $x=\tfrac12$.

Comment: It's always false.

Answer (score 0):

Just do it in cases:

There is a unique integer $n$ and a unique real $y$ where $0\le y < 1$ and $x = n+y$.

Case 1: $y=0$.

Then $\lfloor x \rfloor = \lceil x \rceil = n$.

$\lfloor 2x \rfloor = \lceil 2x \rceil = 2n$

$\lfloor x+\frac 12 \rfloor =  n;   \lceil x +\frac 12 \rceil = n+1$

So $\lfloor 2x \rfloor = \lfloor x \rfloor+\lfloor x+\frac 12 \rfloor$

but $\lceil 2x \rceil \ne \lceil x \rceil + \lceil x +\frac 12 \rceil$.

Case 2:  $0 < y < \frac 12$

Then $\lfloor x \rfloor = n; \lceil x \rceil = n+1$.

$\lfloor 2x \rfloor = 2n;  \lceil 2x \rceil = 2n+1$

$\lfloor x+\frac 12 \rfloor =  n;   \lceil x +\frac 12 \rceil = n+1$

So $\lfloor 2x \rfloor = \lfloor x \rfloor+\lfloor x+\frac 12 \rfloor$

but $\lceil 2x \rceil \ne \lceil x \rceil + \lceil x +\frac 12 \rceil$.

Case 3:  $y=\frac 12$

Then $\lfloor x \rfloor= n; \lceil x \rceil = n+1$.

$\lfloor 2x \rfloor = \lceil 2x \rceil = 2n+1$

$\lfloor x+\frac 12 \rfloor =   \lceil x +\frac 12 \rceil = n+1$

So $\lfloor 2x \rfloor = \lfloor x \rfloor+\lfloor x+\frac 12 \rfloor$

but $\lceil 2x \rceil \ne \lceil x \rceil + \lceil x +\frac 12 \rceil$.

Case 4: $\frac 12 < y < 1$.

Then $\lfloor x \rfloor= n; \lceil x \rceil = n+1$.

$\lfloor 2x \rfloor = 2n+1; \lceil 2x \rceil = 2n+2$

$\lfloor x+\frac 12 \rfloor = n+1  \lceil x +\frac 12 \rceil = n+2$

So $\lfloor 2x \rfloor = \lfloor x \rfloor+\lfloor x+\frac 12 \rfloor$

but $\lceil 2x \rceil \ne \lceil x \rceil + \lceil x +\frac 12 \rceil$.

So your equation is never true.

But it is always true for floor functions.